# How do I hide a button when an IBAction is performed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsbutton

I am attempting to hide a NSButton that performs miniaturize when a different NSButton on the interface is clicked. My attempts thus far have been unsuccessful, this is what I have tried:

.h file:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet WebView *webView;
    IBOutlet NSButton *doMinimize;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet WebView *webView;
```

.m file:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize doMinimize;

- (IBAction)toggleFullscreen:(id)sender
{
...

[doMinimize setEnabled:NO];
[doMinimize setTransparent:YES];

...
}
```

It appears that no matter in what action I try to disable and make the button transparent, it doesn't seem to respond to anything. Do I have to give the button it's own class to make this work? If so, how would I then be able to modify that button from an IBAction inside of a different class?

I apologize in advance if my question is silly, I'm relatively new to the world of Objective-C and am just now starting to get my feet wet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `-setHidden:`?

```
[doMinimize setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Yes, no matter what method I've tried, nothing seems to work. I guess the bigger problem may be that I have not set up the button correctly. It simply has an NSButton class.

Comment: @specik, did you attached the IBOutlet doMinimize with the button in interface builder?

Comment: @Waqas Nope. Just did that now and it seems to be working. Did not realize I needed to attach it in IB. Thank you.

Comment: @specik Every `IBOutlet` must be linked to the appropriate nib object in Interface Builder before you can use it in your code.